# Rounding a rational number to the nearest integer, with half-up

Tags: python, fractions

Given a rational number, I need to get the nearest integer, with exact halves rounded **up** (that is, towards positive infinity). The results **must be exact**, which rules out `float` and `Decimal`, both of which have finite precision.

The following code works perfectly in all cases *except for negative numbers*:

```py
def roundhalfup(x: Fraction) -> int:
    "Returns the closest integer to x, with exact ties rounded up"
    #assert not x < 0, ValueError("Negative numbers not implemented")
    return int(x + Fraction(1, 2))

def divroundhalfup(a: int | Fraction, b: int | Fraction) -> int:
    return roundhalfup(Fraction(a, b))
```

For instance, it succeeds on:

- (5, 3) → 2
- (4, 3) → 1
- (1, 1) → 1
- (2, 3) → 1
- (1, 2) → 1
- (1, 3) → 0
- (0, 1) → 0
- (-1, 3) → 0
- (-1, 2) → 0

But it fails on

- (-2, 3) → 0 [Should be -0.6̅ → -1]
- (-3, 3) → 0 [Should be -1 → -1]
- (-4, 3) → 0 [Should be -1.3̅ → -1]
- (-5, 3) → -1 [Should be -1.6̅ → -2]

I know this could be kludged by using `Decimal` with [`ROUND_HALF_UP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) and `decimal.getcontext().prec=99999`, but I'd like to avoid such an ugly hack if possible. How can this be done *without any rounding* -- purely integrally?

Comment: Check if the fraction is a multiple of `1/2`. If it is, add `1/2` to it. Otherwise, round it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `roundhalfup`, replace `int(...)` with `math.floor(...)`:

```
from math import floor


def roundhalfup(x: Fraction) -> int:
    """
    Returns the closest integer to x, with exact ties rounded up.
    """
    return floor(x + Fraction(1, 2))
```

Comment: Ah, I was worried that anything from the `math` library would have an internal cast-to-`float` addiction; I now see that [`Fraction` actually implements `floor` losslessly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.__floor__)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `round`.
Although since [`Fraction.__round__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.__round__) performs a "round toward even" rather than "round up", it is a little bit more fancy:

```py
from fractions import Fraction

def round_half_up(x: Fraction):
    if x.denominator == 2:
        if x.numerator % 2:
            return round(x + Fraction(1/2))
    else:
        return round(x)

X = [(5, 3), (4, 3), (1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (-1, 3), (-1, 2),
     (-2, 3), (-3, 3), (-4, 3), (-5, 3),
     (3, 2)]

for x in X:
    f = Fraction(*x)
    print(f"{x}\t-> {round_half_up(f)}")
```

Output:

```
(5, 3)  -> 2
(4, 3)  -> 1
(1, 1)  -> 1
(2, 3)  -> 1
(1, 2)  -> 1
(1, 3)  -> 0
(0, 1)  -> 0
(-1, 3) -> 0
(-1, 2) -> 0
(-2, 3) -> -1
(-3, 3) -> -1
(-4, 3) -> -1
(-5, 3) -> -2
(3, 2)  -> 2
```